# ssconvert returns killed with no output

Tags: excel, csv, gnumeric, ssconvert

I am using `ssconvert` (Gnumeric) to convert large Excel files into separate CSV files. Most files work, however with some of the larger files with additional formatting the process dies abruptly and says 'killed'.

```
 ssconvert -S '/tmp/inputfile.xlsx' '/tmp/output.csv'
```

Is there any special handling for larger files that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

If the user or sysadmin did not kill the program the kernel may have. The kernel would only kill a process under exceptional circumstances such as extreme resource starvation.

```
dmesg | grep -E -i -B100 'killed process'
```